# Java reflections generics - cast by passing a parameter at compile time?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, instantiation

There is a following situation:
A class is given, with a generic field in it. Is it possible to instantiate the field at runtime with an instance of `T`?

```
class Root<T>{
   T var;

   Root(){
     //instantiate var with an instance of T here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a class which extends `Root<T>` and sets the type parameter in its `extends` clause, then it's possible to dig it out using [getGenericSuperclass()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass%28%29). For example [Guice uses this approach](http://blog.publicobject.com/2008/11/guice-punches-erasure-in-face.html) to provide type parameter information to the injected classes.

Otherwise, the best bet is to pass a `Class<T>` instance as constructor parameter and use it. This will also result in simpler code, though a bit more boilerplate for each instantiation of the class.

Comment: +1, or just take in an instance of a generified factory interface.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Java uses *type erasure*, so the generic parameter does not exist at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are given an instance of `T` at runtime, the answer is no because of [java type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). At runtime T is actually replaced with Object so the necessary information doesn't exist. This is the reason that functions like List.toArray require you to pass in a typed array in order to receive a typed result.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know the type of `T` at runtime since it is erased at compile time.

However, you can add a new parameter to your constructor of type `Class<T>`. The compiler will ensure that the object passed is a `Class` instance corresponding to the `T` type you specified for your `Root` instance. In your constructor, you can then use reflection to create a new T instance:

```
class Root<T> {

    T var;

    public Root(Class<T> klass) {
        var = klass.newInstance();
    }

}
```

This supposes your `T` type has a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you really need this functionality you will need to pass in the type in your constructor.

Like this:

```
class Root<T> {
  private T var;

  public Root(Class<T> type) {
    var = type.newInstance();
  }
}
```

This will create an instance via reflection. It will only work if the class passed in has a default constructor. Otherwise you'll need to extend the example.